# How to apply different conditions for same column and output as new columns in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I have a Postgres table that looks like below

```
       ip        |          up_score 
-----------------+-------------------
 223.110.181.122 |                 1
 242.123.249.85  |                 0
 10.110.11.1     |                 1
 10.254.253.1    |                 1
 19.7.40.40      |                 0
 242.123.249.85  |                 1
 10.110.11.1     |                 1
 19.7.40.40      |                 0
 10.254.253.1    |                 0
 223.110.181.122 |                 0
 19.7.40.40      |                 0
 10.254.253.1    |                 1
```

Now I want a separate count of 0s and 1s per ip. I tried the queries below

```
select ip, count(up_score) from net_score where up_score = 0 group by ip;

select ip, count(up_score) from net_score where up_score = 1 group by ip;
```

But I want to combine these two queries together such that on a single execution I get the below result

```
       ip        |    count_1 |    count_0    
-----------------+------------+-----------
 223.110.181.122 |          1 |          1   
 242.123.249.85  |          1 |          1
 10.110.11.1     |          2 |          0
 10.254.253.1    |          2 |          1
 19.7.40.40      |          0 |          3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter clause, something like this (untested):

```sql
select ip, 
       count(*) filter (where up_score = 0) AS count_0,
       count(*) filter (where up_score = 1) AS count_1
from net_score group by ip;
```

edit: unfortunately above does not work for postgres <9.4

Comment: It gives syntax error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("` after `filter`. Can you check?

Comment: Ah -- sorry, didn't realise that filter expressions were introduced after 9.2 (9.4 I believe).  I will provide a 9.2 solution.

Comment: oh I see. ok sure :)

Comment: hey thanks for your solution. It works but I found a simpler solution that uses case expression and used it for my case. I verified that both the queries are giving same result but the one I used is a bit simpler. But thanks for your effort :)

Comment: upvoted your solution in appreciation for your effort :)

Comment: haha nice! I'll probably just remove the FOJ then as it's redundant

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@w08r** for his solution, but I found a simpler solution here (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112797/258199) that uses case expression. I modified it for my own use and used it. I am posting the query below

```
SELECT ip, 
COUNT(case when up_score = 0 
then ip end) as count_0, 
COUNT(case when up_score = 1 
then ip end) as count_1 
FROM net_score 
GROUP BY ip;
```